# How to draw separate texts one by one in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to draw two pieces of text one by one in MFC as they would be part of the same text. Right now I am drawing them as they are just one string:

```
CString text1 = "A text";
CString text2 = "A second text";
CString textToDraw = text1 + text2;
CDC* dc = GetDC(); //assume that this is initialized elsewhere
dc->TextOut(0, 0, textToDraw);
```

It is simple to draw the both texts as one because I only need to find the position where they should be started to be draw. The problem I am facing is how to compute the new X coordinate at which the second text should be draw (considering that the texts can be chosen at run-time so they do not have a known length):

```
dc->TextOut(0, 0, text1);
int X;
//how should I compute X...?
dc->TextOut(X, 0, text2);
```

I appreciate any help received!

Comment: Not easily possible. Why can't you concatenate the strings and render them in one go? A bit more detail: While the proposed answer does compute the area occupied by text, it does not account for character layout where the two strings meet. Specifically, it does not honor [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning), and rendering the strings `"A"` followed by `"V"` will look different than rendering the string `"AV"`, for example.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for the reply! The reason I need to print them as separate pieces of text is because they are and mean different things, and in a particular case, one needs to be bold and another does not. I do not know why mfc does not provide an easy way to print two separate pieces of text one by another. I am sorry that I am asking for this but I am working on a project stuck on mfc.

Comment: That's a fairly uncommon use case, and MFC doesn't try to provide answers for any conceivable problem. It allows you to measure the size of text (as explained in the proposed answer), though. If you need to output more complex formatted text, you could always choose a [CRichEditCtrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68730ktd.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use DrawText() with DT_CALCRECT flag to calculate the **width** and **height** the text would occupy without actually drawing the text. The following may be the answer to your question.

```
dc->TextOut(100, 100, text1);

RECT rect = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
dc->DrawText(text1, &rect, DT_CALCRECT);

dc->TextOut(100 + rect.right, 100, text2);
```